# How to start using arm-linux-gcc in Cygwin

Tags: gcc, arm, cygwin, cross-compiling

### Summarize the question (2018/5/4)

1. I downloaded ARM Linux Toolchain for Cygwin from sourceforge [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/armlinux4cygwin/). It was last updated in 2010.
2. I have a recently installed Cygwin in my win7 PC.
3. And then, I tried to setup the tool. And I could successfully execute `arm-linux-gcc -v`.
4. However, `arm-linux-gcc --target-help` has a problem.

The problem was that it told me file `cygcloog-0.dll` is missing. I don't understand what is going wrong. Based on simple searching, cygcloog-0.dll may be part of cygwin. Is it true? Or maybe it's just because the ARM Linux Toolchain I got is too old to be compatible with Cygwin today? Then where can I get ARM Linux Toolchain for Cygwin?

To be honest, I thought it would be an easy question. But it turns out that maybe not many people are using Cygwin. Is it really that hard to do it on Cygwin, that, I should install Linux?

### Details of the question (mostly written before 2018/3/2)

I want to do cross compiling so I downloaded [ARM Linux Toolchain for Cygwin from SourceForge.net](https://sourceforge.net/projects/armlinux4cygwin/files/latest/download). But I can't find any offical downloads and manual about that. So I'm not sure how to install and use arm-linux-gcc in Cygwin.

The first part is how to install. This is what I've done so far.

1. I extracted the downloaded `arm-linux-toolchain-cygwin-2010q1.tar.bz2` file
   under windows system (say `Z:\`). So folder `Z:\arm-linux` is created.
2. Then I opened Cygwin and added the environment path `Z:\arm-linux\bin` by typing `declare -x PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/z/arm-linux/bin` in Cygwin's Bash command.
3. Then I type `arm-linux-gcc -v` and it seems ok. The output is

:

```
$ arm-linux-gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: arm-linux
Configured with: /home/stargaze/gcc-4.4.3/configure --enable-languages=c,c++ --build=i686-pc-cygwin --disable-libmudflap --disable-libssp --disable-libgomp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-symvers=gnu --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-c99 --enable-long-long --with-dwarf2 -v --target=arm-linux --prefix=/opt/arm-linux --disable-shared --disable-threads --with-gcc --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --enable-interwork --enable-multilib --with-sysroot=/opt/arm-linux/sysroot --disable-nls
Thread model: single
gcc version 4.4.3 (GCC)
```

4. But when I tried to get more information typing `arm-linux-gcc --target-help`, I was told that a dll file is missing

:

```
$ arm-linux-gcc --target-help
Z:/arm-linux/libexec/gcc/arm-linux/4.4.3/cc1.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygcloog-0.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The cygcloog-0.dll should be a missing file of Cygwin.

That's all I've done so far to install. I'm not sure whether that's all the install process.

Part 2, how to use `arm-linux-gcc`. I didn't do further testing because I don't know how to use `arm-linux-gcc` yet.

EDIT: After @matzeri 's reply, I followed his instruction and it works. So I can find the manual of `arm-linux-gcc` now. It is the `arm-linux-gcc.1` file. 
His instruction is `cd /cygdrive/z/arm-linux` and `man man/man1/arm-linux-gcc.1`. It is the same as my operation which is `declare -x PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/z/arm-linux/bin` and `man arm-linux-gcc`. I was asking because I thought there was something wrong. Now I'm sure there's nothing wrong.

Comment: use `man` for reading manual files. try `cd /cygdrive/z/arm-linux` and `man  man/man1/arm-linux-gcc.1`